# 'Malformed reference element' when signing SAML assertion with x509 certificate

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am building a SAML IdP to handle SSO between a Student Portal, and a third party system. My code is based on on the [CoverMyMeds Test Harness](https://github.com/covermymeds/saml-http-post-reference), and I have used some of their unaltered libraries in my project. I have also set up their sample identity provider to make it easier to debug this issue.

The page I built off of this foundation to handle authentication takes a GUID from the Student Portal, using it to retrieve student details from an internal service and package it into a SAML assertion, which is then signed with an x.509 certificate before sending it off to the 3rd party SAML service provider. It is here that I am stuck. When attempting to sign the SAML request I receive:

[image: Malformed Reference Element]
<sub>(source: [tennysonhull.com](http://tennysonhull.com/Public/StackOverflow/SigningSAMLAssertionError.png))</sub>

The debugging and research I've done seems to indicate that the code is not the problem, but just so you understand how I got here: The `ComputeSignature()` call is coming from the [CertificateUtility -> AppendSignatureToXMLDocument method](https://github.com/covermymeds/saml-http-post-reference/blob/master/CMMSAMLLibrary/CertificateUtility.cs#L69), which is being called from [SAML20Assertion -> SerializeAndSignSAMLResponse method](https://github.com/covermymeds/saml-http-post-reference/blob/master/CMMSAMLLibrary/SAML20Assertion.cs#L90), which is being called indirectly by the [IdPLauncher.aspx page](https://github.com/covermymeds/saml-http-post-reference/blob/master/CMMSAMLIdentityProvider/IdPLauncher.aspx.cs#L62).

[This is what the assertion looks like](https://gist.github.com/pyrotek/8d3f3a7f50d3121b70d9) before I attempt to sign the package. I've examined this thoroughly and have run it through debuggers without finding an issue with it.

My hypothesis is that there is something wrong with the certificate, which is self signed for testing purposes. The company I am working with assures me that other people who have integrated have used test certs in the past, but I can think of no other reason why this would be failing.  Though I have tried numerous variations, the command I thought most likely to produce a working test certificate based on my research is: `makecert.exe -a md5 -r -pe -n "CN=iGradTest"  -ss my -sr localmachine -sky signature "c:\iGradTest.cer"`, but the resultant certificates continue to have the same issue.  The generated certificate has been given a friendly name and set up to work with IIS using winhttpcertcfg. The app is successfully obtaining the certificate, but failing when attempting to add it to the assertion.

I am at a loss for what to do next. Any advice on next steps to identify and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read/assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception you are facing means that the `URI` of the reference does not resolve to another element tagged with an `ID` attribute.

Based off of the code provided, SAML20Assertion.cs:90 is prepending a `#` to the ID, then CertificateUtility.cs:69 is prepending it again.  Remove it from one of the locations, and all is well.

SAML20Assertion.cs:90:

```
CertificateUtility.AppendSignatureToXMLDocument(ref xmlResponse, "#" + ((AssertionType)Response.Items[0]).ID, SigningCert);
```

Should be

```
CertificateUtility.AppendSignatureToXMLDocument(ref xmlResponse, ((AssertionType)Response.Items[0]).ID, SigningCert);
```